# Ant copy files by reading property file

Tags: file, ant, properties, copy

I have 2 set of properties.One is list of files and other is list of dirs. Like this

> Files=file1,file2,file3,file4
>
> destination.dir=dir1,dir2,dir3,dir4

These 2 properties are defined in build.properties.

I want to copy file1 to dir1,file2 to dir2 and so on.

How can I achieve this in ant?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

a solution with Ant addon [**Flaka**](http://code.google.com/p/flaka/)

```
<project xmlns:fl="antlib:it.haefelinger.flaka">
<!-- make standard ant tasks like copy understand EL expressions -->
<fl:install-property-handler />

<property name="files" value="/some/path/file1,/some/path/file2,/some/path/file3,/some/path/file4"/>
<property name="destination.dir" value="/some/otherpath/dir1,/some/otherpath/dir2,/some/otherpath/dir3,/some/otherpath/dir4"/>

 <!-- iterate over the csv property destination.dir -->
 <fl:for var="dir" in="split('${destination.dir}', ',')">
  <!-- copy the first item from csv property ${files} -->
  <copy file="#{split('${files}',',')[0]}" todir="#{dir}" verbose="true"/>
  <!--
     afterwards delete this file item from csv property ${files}, means
     editing and overwriting ${files} for the next loop
  -->
    <fl:let>files ::= replace('${files}', '' , '#{split('${files}',',')[0]},?' )</fl:let>
 </fl:for>

</project>
```

alternatively use some scripting language as groovy, beanshell, (j)ruby, javascript .. within script task